# Dynamic Output during ParallelMap

Tags: dynamic, parallelization

I can't seem to figure out how to dynamically output a variable that is being used in a parallel evaluation. Below is an example function that demonstrates my problem.

```
TestCount[n_Integer] := Module[{bar, i},
   bar = PrintTemporary[Dynamic[i], " ", ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[i/n]], " ", n];
   Do[(*Nothing Really*), {i, n}];
];
```

Running `TestCount[123456789]` works as expected and prints a nice temporary progress bar, but running it in parallel with `ParallelMap[TestCount, {123456789, 98765432}]` doesn't properly print the value of `i`, but instead prints `i$208` or with some number other than `208`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three changes are needed to make this code work:

1. Move `PrintTemporary` inside the `Do` loop, so that it can access `i`.
2. Remove `i` from the list of `Module` temporary variables.  You may as well eliminate the symbol `bar` as well, because there is no need for it.
3. Replace `Dynamic[i]` with `With[{i = i}, Dynamic[i]]`, as aptly explained in "A Good Trick to Know" of [Introduction to Dynamic](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToDynamic.html).

With these changes, the code becomes

```
TestCount[n_Integer] := Module[{}, Do[PrintTemporary[With[{i = i}, Dynamic[i]], " ",
    With[{i = i}, ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[i/n]]], " ", n]; Pause[1], {i, n}]];
```

and

```
TestCount[10]
```

produces a list of ten `ProgressIndicator` bars, numbered 1 - 10, and then erases them at the end of the loop, as expected

Perhaps more useful would be to move `ProgressIndicator` outside the `Module`

```
ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[x]]

TestCount[n_Integer] := Module[{}, Do[Pause[1]; 
    PrintTemporary[i, " ", With[{i = i}, Dynamic[x = N[i/n]]]], {i, n}]]
```

which produces a single `ProgressIndicator` bar that follows the progress of the loop, as well as temporarily printing `i` and `x`.